# RFSniffer and Transmitter program for 434 mhz receiver and transmitter

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio

In the past, I have successfully build a solution to control my etekcity smart plugs working on 433 mhz using the RFSniffer and transmitter ( RFOutlet ) etc. programs.

Currently i am trying to control my hunters fan whose remote works on 434 mhz and not on 433mhz. I purchased the transmitter ( 4 pins ) and receivers ( 8 pins ) for the same but not finding any RFSniffer kind of programs ( any language like python, node.js, javascript etc. ) to use with the 434 mhz transmitter and receiver.

Want to first find the various signals the switches ( on / off, light, fan speed ) on the remote transmit and then transmit the same signal via the 434 mhz transmitter connected on the Raspberrypi.

In conclusion, I am looking for a RFSniffer kind of program for Raspberry pi that works ( detects and transmit ) with 434 mhz frequency.

Comment: The software does not know or care if the frequency is 433 or 434 (actually the same) or 868. If the software doesn't work it is because the device uses a different protocol.

Comment: why did you not use the same equipment that you used to decode the communication protocol of the smart plugs to decode the fan protocol?